# how can I use Text datatype in app engine entity

Tags: android, google-app-engine, entity

I am getting problems in using Text datatype in entity class for storing values more than 500  characters long while using app engine. As com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text is not available in my android activity class, how do I create a Text datatype in my android class?

I tried using below code while defining my entity class, but I still get illegalargument exception when trying to use get/set methods in my android activity class.

```
private Text storyContent;
 public String getStoryContent() {return storyContent.getValue();}
 public void setStoryContent(String storyContentString) {
    this.storyContent=new Text(storyContentString);
    }
```

Comment: There's no need (and no way) to use Datastore classes on Android. On Android, use a String for any size. The fact that Datastore makes a difference between string and text properties doesn't concern your Android app.

Comment: I was simply using String type earlier. But I was getting the following error               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String properties must be 500 characters or less. The string values were more than 500 characters long.

Comment: Use String on Android, Text on AppEngine. You cannot share that code between your Android app and AppEngine app, so it's not an issue that the Datastore Text class isn't available for Android.

Comment: How do I use Text in AppEngine and String in android? If I define a property within my entity bean as type Text then the corresponding get and set methods in my android class expect Text type arguments but not String. My problem is not how to use Text type in android, but it is how to store a value more than 500 characters long in my Datastore(in an endpoint environment).

Comment: Don't expose the fact that the field in your entity is Text (that's an implementation detail), make the getter return text.getValue() which is a String. If you need a setter, make it take a String and set a `new Text(someString)` into the field.

Comment: if you look at the code I had posted in my question, that's exactly how I wanted to handle this. Somehow that was not working in app engine sdk 1.8. After updating to version 1.8.1 it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

updating App engine SDK to the latest one(1.8) seems to have resolve the issues. Looks like it was a known issue in app engine. I guess for longer than 500 characters long values, datastore is internally converting to Text type. hence I can see my values are being stored at Text type in datastore viewer.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9035

Comment: Are you using `FileServiceImpl.getBlobKey()`? If not, this issue doesn't affect you.